# Elasticsearch Indexing bulk data - java API

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the elastic search doc when we want to index bulk data at once we can use

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

// either use client#prepare, or use Requests# to directly build index/delete requests
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                    .endObject()
                  )
        );

bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "2")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                        .field("message", "another post")
                    .endObject()
                  )
        );
```

This is ok if we have like 10 different data to put to index but i have over 250 data to put to index, my data is in json format currently as listed below

```
[
  {
    "departure": {
      "city": "\u041c\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a",
      "date": "Aug 27, 2018 12:09:00 AM"
    },
    "extras": [],
    "hotel": {
      "beach": {
        "distance": 0,
        "type": "\u041f\u0435\u0441\u0447\u0430\u043d\u044b\u0439"
      },
      "country": "\u0413\u0440\u0435\u0446\u0438\u044f",
      "distanceToAirport": 0,
      "facilities": [
        "Standard"
      ],
      "food": "\u0412\u0441\ 4e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043e",
      "photoUrl": "https://s1.tez-tour.com/hotel/7019851/low_SWIMMING_POOL3_4931_small.jpg",
      "regionName": "\u041a\u0 18\u0440\u0430\u043a\u043b\u0438\u043e\u043d",
      "stars": 4,
      "title": "LAVRIS HOTELS & SPA"
    },
    "nights": 9,
    "people": 1,
    "price": 1967,
    "typeOfRest": "\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0435\u0439\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0420\u043e\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0438\u043a \u0410\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0439"
  },
  {
    "departure": {
      "city": "\u041c\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a",
      "date": "Aug 26, 2018 12:08:00 AM"
    },
    "extras": [],
    "hotel": {
      "beach": {
        "distance": 0,
        "type": "\u041f\u0435\u0441\u0447\u0430\u043d\u044b\u0439"
      },
      "country": "\u0413\u0440\u0435\u0446\u0438\u044f",
      "distanceToAirport": 0,
      "facilities": [
        "Standard"
      ],
      "food": "\u0417\u0430\u0432\u0442\"\u0438\u043d",
      "photoUrl": "https://s.tez-tour.com/hotel/7024462/zpanoramic3_5452_small.jpg",
      "regionName": "\u041a\u0440\u0438\u0442\"
      "stars": 4,
      "title": "GLAROS BEACH HOTEL"
    },
    "nights": 7,
    "people": 1,
    "price": 2217,
    "typeOfRest": "\u0421\u0435\u043c 
  },
```

I have over 200 of such data , is there a better way to index all at once than writing all of it to fields. May to call from class path, as all my data are in a file called tour.json